# Replace a string within a line, by the content of a file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, scripting, aix

I have a file "tmp.txt":

```
Hi@@xml-record@@Bye
```

And I want to replace the '@@xml-record@@' by all the content of the file f1.txt:

```
file1
```

The result that I want is:

```
Hifile1Bye
```

I have try this option without a good result:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)@@xml-record@@\(.*\)/echo '\''\1'\''$(cat f1.txt)'\''\2'\''/e' tmp.txt
awk 'BEGIN { FS="@@"; } { if ($2 =="xml-record" )print $1 $(<f1.txt) $3; else print $0; }' tmp.txt
```

This works if I don't have anything else in the line:

```
awk '/@@xml-record@@/{system("cat f1.txt");next}1' tmp.txt > awk.txt
```

That's how it works, but I can't do it for variables because the file f1.txt is too big:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="@@"; cmd ="cat f1.txt" cmd|getline VAR close(cmd)  } { if ($2 =="xml-record" )print $1 VAR $3; else print $0; }' tmp.txt
```

I'm on an AIX machine, so some awk functions are not available to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "s/@\+[^@]*@\+/$(< f1.txt)/" tmp.txt
Hifile1Bye
```

Comment: @Oscar Does the edit work?

Comment: Yes "edit [ -r ] [ File ... ]"

Comment: sed "s/@\+[^@]*@\+/$(< f1.txt)/" tmp.txt   -> This returns the same thing to me, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `@\+[^@]*@\+` != `@@xml-record@@`. Consider a line containing 2 email addresses, for example - `joe@gmail.com, sue@yahoo.com, and @@xml-record@@ stuff`. More importantly, that replacement would fail in various ways given various characters/strings present in `f1.txt` - `\1`, `&`, `/`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
        old = "@@xml-record@@"
    }
    s = index($0,old) {
        head = substr($0,1,s-1)
        tail = substr($0,s+length(old))
        while ( (getline line < "f1.txt") > 0 ) {
            printf "%s%s", head, line
            head = ORS
        }
        $0 = tail
    }
    { print }
' tmp.txt
Hifile1Bye
```

The above is doing a literal string replacement so it'll work no matter which characters `f1.txt` contains.